# How to strtok() string using the null character as the delimiter?

Tags: c, parsing, strtok

I tried inputting the null character into the list of delimiters but it would not accept it. I tried inputting "\0" but it wouldn't accept it. I even tried putting in the double quotes with escape characters but it still  would not accept it.

Is there a way I could do this?

Comment: How do you distinguish a `'\0'` separator from the null terminator?

Comment: Do you know the length of your string ?

Comment: You must either know the length of your string in advance, or have an alternative ending marker. There is no other way to make it work.

Comment: `strchr(string, '\0');` works. I've told you many times now, don't use `strtok()`.

Comment: Your string doesn't contain any null characters, so what's the point of trying to split it on null characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are allowed to end your string with a double `\0` as sentinel you can build your own function, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s = "abc\0def\0ghi\0";
    char *p = s;

    while (*p) {
        puts(p);
        p = strchr(p, '\0');
        p++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Comment: `p = strchr(p, '\0');` or just `p += strlen(p);`  to  avoid `p++`

Comment: @milevyo: actually `p += strlen(p) + 1;` to avoid `p++`.

Comment: @chqrlie, thank you, of course

Answer (score 3):

According to [strtok(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) this function is used to isolate sequential tokens in a *null-terminated* string. So the answer is no, not using strtok, since that function cannot compare a `\0` separator from the terminator. You will have to write your own function (which is trivial).

Also read the BUGS section in the [strtok man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) ... better avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

For better or worse, C decided that all strings are null terminated, so you can't parse based on that character.

One workaround would be to replace all nulls in your (non-string) binary buffer with something you know doesn't occur in the buffer, then use that as your separator treating the buffer as char*.

Answer (score 0):

In C, strings are just char arrays that must end with a null character.  If a string in memory is not terminated that way, the program will endlessly read memory until a null char is found and there is no way to determine where it will be since memory changes constantly.  Your best bet is to create an array of char pointers (strings) and populate them using better organization.